# CSS how can I get an inline display with a working ::first-line pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

This looks very simple, but I couldn't get it working, either with combinations of `float`, `inline-block` and so on. I am trying to get more space on the first line so that the second one doesn't "collide" with the header. I know that `::first-line` doesn't work on `inline` elements. I want to keep this layout (the layout is what's important, not the `inline` display, so whatever works is OK). The solution should have a wide browser support.

My design must stay responsive, so the text shouldn't be cut in different parts. I could do it in javascript and keep it responsive by running a script on `resize`, but I really would like to avoid this solution.

**EDIT:** @TemaniAfif's comment about setting `inline-block` to the header does the trick for my special case, but for curiosity and future readers, it doesn't directly answer for the pseudo-element. For example if someone wanter to capitalize or change color, I feel the question is still valid, so I'm editing the snippet.

```css
.heading {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.content::first-line {
  line-height: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<b>Display is fine, first-line doesn't work because of inline + margin left works fine:</b>
<br><br>

<span class="heading">header: </span>
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

<br><br>
<b>Display is out now that first-line works because of block (or inline-block) + margin left out too:</b>
<br><br>

<span class="heading">header: </span>
<span class="content block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
```

Comment: making the header `display: inline-block;` seems to fix the issue, no?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it makes no sense, as the content stays `inline` so `::first-line` shouldn't apply, but it seems to, thanks! Add an answer and I'll accept it (if you have the explanation too i'd be really happy)

Comment: first-line is useless and is not applying even if you make the header inline-block. Simply remove it. The inline-block is making the height of the first line bigger

Comment: @TemaniAfif CSS is a weird animal sometimes, thanks for all, edited the question in case someone has the general case answer for future readers.

Comment: for the second case, float is the solution. In this case you can keep the block display and use first-line and have the header inline with the text

Answer (score 1):

You can try `display: inline-block;` in your .heading

```css
.heading {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.content::first-line {
  line-height: 2;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<b>Display is fine, first-line doesn't work because of inline + margin left works fine:</b>
<br><br>

<span class="heading">header: </span>
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

<br><br>
<b>Display is out now that first-line works because of block (or inline-block) + margin left out too:</b>
<br><br>

<span class="heading">header: </span>
<span class="content block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question for it to be useful for the general case, I'll upvote but won't accept until someone has a more general answer for other properties.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really describe what should be aligned how, but by combining `float:left;` and  a negative `margin-top` setting for that first-word `span` (also with values different from what I used below) you should be able to get what you want:

```css
.heading {
  float:left;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<b>Display is fine, first-line doesn't work because of inline + margin left works fine:</b>
<br><br>

<span class="heading">header: </span>
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question for it to be useful for the general case, I'll upvote but won't accept until someone has a more general answer for other properties.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box-text { position:relative;}
.box-text p::first-line { display:inline-block; position:relative; color:#ccc;}
.box-text p { display:inline-block; position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="box-text">

<p>header:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>

<div class="box-text">

<p>header:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>

<div class="box-text">

<p>header:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but this one won't do: the goal of the whole layout is to have the "header" on the same line as the content, and whatever the header width, the content should fill the remaining space, then on the new line fill the whole width. Same behaviour as 2 `inline` elements or one with `float: left` and the other `inline`.